# Ask about the copyright of develop destop application based on web application

Tags: desktop

I googled and found some web online calculators (such as BodyFatCalculator & CaloricCalculator).

I plan to develop the desktop Calculators in C# (WPF & .net 3.5). But I would test the online function and build my application model (I think some body properties not suit for Asian people, maybe I still need do more research.).

But now I must study others web app before my desktop app design. Could I develop my app without the web application owner's permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't using any of the original code and haven't been looking at the original code from the web application, and as long as your aren't cloning their interface or infringing any of their patents, then you should be fine. The copyright only applies to the code, and you are fine as long as you don't copy the code... however, you shouldn't even look at the code so that there is no question that you didn't copy it.